# Validating empty fields with inline validation method and validator class

Tags: validation, jsf-2

I have the following input field:

```
<h:inputText value=".." validator="#{labController.validateValue}"/>
```

If the field is empty it will not be validated (`validateValue` in `labController` is not called).

But using a separate validator class:

```
<h:inputText value=".." >
  <f:validator validatorId="labDateValidator"/>
</h:inputText>
```

then its `validate` method well be called even with an empty input field?

This is what I observe. Is this behavior dependent on implementation or version (I am using Mojarra 2.1) ?

Background is that I want to use my own method/class for all validation tasks including required validation. Does it work with validator class only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've hit an oversight in JSF. The `validator` is wrapped in a [`MethodExpressionValidator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/MethodExpressionValidator.html) which according to the source of its [`validate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/MethodExpressionValidator.html#validate%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIComponent,%20java.lang.Object%29) method indeed skips validation when the value is `null`.

```
if (value != null) {
    try {
        ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();
        methodExpression.invoke(elContext, new Object[]{context, component, value});
        ...
```

This is not considering the new JSF 2.0 `javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS` context parameter which defaults to `true`. It should actually be doing the same as [`UIInput#validate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#validate%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29).

```
if (!isEmpty(newValue) || validateEmptyFields(context)) {
    try {
        ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();
        methodExpression.invoke(elContext, new Object[]{context, component, value});
        ...
```

This has already been reported as [Mojarra issue 1508](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1508). I've voted it and added a new comment to wake them up.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, BalusC. Fortunately I could outsource my validation method into a validator class without problems. (Comment on the bug page: "These will all be done for GF 3.1 M6 at the latest!":-)

Comment: Which was released over 1 year ago. Apparently not done yet :)

Comment: @MattHandy: I have something different here: for `p:inputText`, I can use both either `validator` attribute in the `p:inputText` or `f:validator`. However for `p:selectOneMenu`, only `f:validator` work. Do we know when JSF 2.2 suppose to be release?